# How to stop a win32 thread that is blocking?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, concurrency

I've created a custom `ThreadPool` which starts a number of win32 threads with `_beginthreadex()`. The threads are running a simple loop that attempts to dequeue tasks from a blocking queue, but sometimes I need to stop the threads and if they're blocked on `Dequeue` then I don't know how to get the threads out of that blocking state.

```
void ThreadPool::Loop()
{
    while(_running)
    {
        try
        {
            // Attempts to dequeue a task and run it
            _taskQueue.Dequeue()->Run();
        }
        catch(BlockingQueueTerminate&)
        {
            // Eat the exception and check the running flag
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

My idea was to enqueue the same number of special tasks (let's call them "termination tasks") as there are threads in the pool and each "termination task" will call `_endthreadex(0)` in order to exit the thread. If there are other tasks in the blocking queue, then I won't really care because as soon as I dequeue a task, I will run it and I will check the `_running` flag to determine if the thread needs to dequeue any more tasks.

```
void TerminationTask::Run()
{
    _endthreadex(0);
}
```

I have several concerns about this approach; mainly, if I processed a non-terminating task and the `_running` flag is set to `false`, then my thread will not call `_endthreadex(0)` when it exits the loop. I was wondering if I could call `_endthreadex(0)` at the end of the loop like this:

```
void ThreadPool::Loop()
{
    while(_running)
    {
        try
        {
            // Attempts to dequeue a task and run it
            _taskQueue.Dequeue()->Run();
        }
        catch(BlockingQueueTerminate&)
        {
            // Eat the exception and check the running flag
            continue;
        }
    }
    _endthreadex(0);
}
```

Will this cause a conflict with my `TerminationTask` or will the thread exit the loop directly after executing `TerminationTask::Run()` (i.e. it won't call `_endthreadex(0)` twice)? Furthermore, is there a better approach than this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `_endthreadex(0)` at the end of the thread method is fine. It is also optional. If you just leave the thread method normally, then `_endthreadex(0)` is called for you.

> You can call _endthread or _endthreadex explicitly to terminate a thread; however, _endthread or _endthreadex is called automatically when the thread returns from the routine passed as a parameter to _beginthread or _beginthreadex.<sup>[ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw264s73%28VS.80%29.aspx)</sup>

Sending a termination task is the correct way to get a blocked thread pool thread to unblock and quit.

So, to summarise:

1. Your strategy is good and the implementation of `TerminationTask::Run` is correct.
2. You can remove the harmless call to `_endthreadex(0)` at the end of `ThreadPool::Loop`.

Comment: Ah, got it... I will remove the unneeded `_endthreadex(0)`! Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: As an aside, do you need the `while (_running)` loop? Whenever I've done this I've written `while (true)` and then sent a termination task to bring an end to proceedings. Since you have a termination mechanism in place, it seems spurious to have yet another one in the `_running` flag. Indeed I suspect that done this way you code would be needlessly complex and carry the potential for race conditions.

Comment: I need the `_running` flag in case I have a ton of tasks in queue and I want to terminate prior to processing all the tasks. The termination task is only helpful when I have no tasks in queue and I want to get out of the blocking state. In other words: I can have a `ThreadPool::Terminate` (which allows all the tasks to be processed by simply adding a `TerminateTask` to the end of the blocking queue and disabling the enqueuing) and I could have a `ThreadPool::TerminateNow` method which simply stops processing tasks regardless of what's in the queue.

Comment: +1 but another couple options might be 1) set a "death event" specifically to wake up a thread blocked in `WaitForMultipleObjects` or 2) Send a "death job" via `QueueUserAPC`

Comment: @JohnDibling can you explain how to do that? Your comment got me thinking about the case when the `Runnable` task has some blocking code... I don't have control of that, so would it be a good policy to interrupt the `Runnable` too? Perhaps I should implement some kind of a policy for the `Runnable` so that it has an "interrupt" method which takes it out of a blocking state (which would be the responsibility of the person implementing the interface to guarantee that).

Comment: Pretty hard to implement asynchronous cancelling. Frameworks like .net offer that level of functionality. Another thought, doesn't the standard Windows thread pool do what you need. You did tag the question winapi after all.

Comment: @David, for some reason I had concluded that the Windows `ThreadPool` was insufficient in some manner, so I decided to write my own `ThreadPool` which mimics the behavior of the Java `ThreadPool` (I just like the way it works in Java). However, I'll take a look at the winapi again and I'll try to see if I really had a valid reason not to use the winapi `ThreadPool`.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a temination task in the Queue is correct.  I would try a different approach to handling it, though:

```
class TerminateThreadNow {};

void TerminationTask::Run()
{
    throw TerminateThreadNow();
} 

void ThreadPool::Loop()
{
    while(_running)
    {
        try
        {
            // Attempts to dequeue a task and run it
            _taskQueue.Dequeue()->Run();
        }
        catch(TerminateThreadNow&)
        {
            _running = false;
        }
        catch(BlockingQueueTerminate&)
        {
            // Eat the exception and check the running flag
        }
    }
}
```